# Eclipse Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I started up the eclipse (Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0) Build id: 20220609-1112) program on windows 10 on my PC today. My vision is rather poor due to some eye surgery, but it seemed like the splash screen was different.

It seems like every source file I edit (as well as a creating new class) results in a: " Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level 17, preview can be enabled only at source level 18 ". Cleaning, opening and closing the project does not help. Java compiler options are all set at 17. Opening up another project and editing a source file results in the same error.

No class files are produced in bin/. Gradle tests run fine. Gradle *does* have a warning: "warning: [removal] JApplet in javax.swing has been deprecated and  marked for removal."

Opening a new project seems to work ok.

Cloning the repo gets the same error on the first source file. Editing a source file gets the error. Doing a git reset --hard after the edit does *not* fix the error.

Edit 1: Made a new project in eclipse and copied the source code (sans git) to it. Most things seem to work so far. New project has a specific classpath entry: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-17, the original has:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
```

Comment: What Java is set as the default in "Java > Installed JREs" in the Preferences? In the Project Properties what Java is show in the Java Build Path?

Comment: Also look at the compliance level and preview settings in both "Java > Compiler" in the Preferences, and "Java Compiler" in the project Properties.

Comment: default jre is 17, build jdkl 17.0.1, compliance are se17 and inherited for the project. if i run from the command line, i need --enable-preview.  build.gradle does not have the preview switch. new eclipse project works fine with git now.

Answer (score 5):

The **Eclipse** Java IDE, or to be more precise [Eclipse JDT](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/), **supports** multiple Java versions, but the **preview features of the latest Java version only**. This means, in Eclipse 2022-06 (4.24.0) preview features are only available for Java 18.

Preview features should not be used in production and are there to make it easier to try out future changes. But with the release of Java 18, the preview features of Java 17 become a preview of a future that is already past.

Keep also in mind that Eclipse has its own incremental Java compiler and that the decision was made only to support the preview features of the latest Java version in Eclipse.